# two conditions in an IF statement (C Language)

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

How can I write this statement correctly in C language?
I want to say that If money = 4.59163e-41  AND 0 then.....

```
if (money = 4.59163e-41 && 0 ) 
printf(" You can't play for free! Bet some money! \n");
else
printf(" You are ready to start!! \n");
```

Comment: I realize it's unlikely to matter for your program, but it's bad practice to use floats/doubles for currency values. Use scaled integers. While I'm nitpicking, it's also bad to compare floats/doubles for equality, as you may get differences beyond the significant figures shown.

Comment: A good way to avoid mistaking the `=` for the `==` operator is to write the expression backwards - e.g. `if (4.59163e-41 == money..)` this will give you an error if you use `=` instead because you cannot assign to literals.

Comment: "I want to say that If money = 4.59163e-41 AND 0"  What makes you think that a variable can have two different values at once?

Comment: Even if you use `==` the above expression will always evaluate to false because of 0 at the end. Everything *and* with false is false

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to do something like this.  take note of the `==` instead of `=`.

```
if (money == 4.59163e-41 || money == 0 )
```

`=` is assignment, not comparison.

Comment: so by "AND" you meant "OR"... righto